# Why must $n$ be even if $2^n+1$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory

This is a necessary step in a problem I am working on.

Comment: $n=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: **Hint:** Prove this similar statement: $2^n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ for all odd $n$.

Comment: You can factor a sum of two $k$th powers, where $k$ is odd.

Comment: These primes are sometimes called fermat primes

Answer (score 3):

$n$ has to be a power of $2$.

suppose $n$ is not a power of $2$, then let $n=dk$ with $d$ odd.

Then $2^n+1=(2^k)^d+1=(2^k)^d+1^d$ ,now use the high school factorization for $x^d +y^d$ which is true when $d$ is odd that says $x^d+y^d=(x+y)(x^{d-1}-x^{d-2}y+x^{d-3}y^2\dots +y^{d-1})$.

In this case $x=2^k$ and $y=1$.

We get:

$(2^k)^d+1=(2^k+1)((2^k)^{d-1}-(2^{k})^{d-2}+(2^k)^{d-3}\dots +1)$ This tells us our number is not prime.

---

Fenyang Wang gives a simpler way to prove the number must be even.

this is because if it was odd it would be a multiple of three, and the only prime multiple of three is three.

However it is useful to note the number has to be a power of two, since powers of two are a lot scarcer than even numbers. Also notice that in my solution you can exchange $2$ for any positive integer other than $2$.

Comment: Shouldn't you verify that none of the factors (in the final expression) are units?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: Haha, ok I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the high-school identity:
$$x^n+1=(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+\dots-x+1),$$
which is valid if and only if $n$ is odd.